# Blender Internal SSS material/node setup not working

Tags: node-editor, subsurface-scattering

trying out an old node setup for Blender Internal, but for some reason its not working. As far as i know, it should be working. Any suggestions will be much appreciated. (Unless it's "use Cycles").[image]

Comment: A better comparison would be between the skin material with the backscattering nodes connected and disconnected. Currently we have no base skin material to compare to, so it could be that the backscattering is just very weak and thus not very visible.

Comment: That was it Branticus, i needed to crank up the back value on the backscatter material to insanity and beyond (max value of 10). Interesting though is that if i set the back value on the peach colored material to 1 it has the same effect as the backscatter material has on 10, except it affects the whole body, which is undesirable. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Sorry * Brenticus